UEFI Boot options not triggered by tapping esc, F1, F2 or F12 in 7.1 OS running on Mac Mini mid-2011
After having installed EoS 7.1 on my Mac Mini mid-2011, I have flashed a bootable USB with High Sierra ready to set up a dual boot, as I'd like to have proper access to iTunes.
When installing Horus on my mac, using a wireless keyboard, it was critical to press the appropriate key at the appropriate time to get the USB to show up.
With Horus installed, if I tap esc the GRUB screen appears, tapping F1, F2 or F12 does nothing. I copy and paste when I'm using terminal, as I'm a basic user and am not knowledgeable when it comes to command line stuff.
I've read that sometimes its an issue with the current OS loading too quickly to get into UEFI, and that can be altered, but I'm hoping that I'm just not pressing the right key at the right time.
